# Split main JS bundle of an angular app based on component

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, angular-cli, angular-components

I have developed an angular 4 web application, which has 3 components and all are independent components.

```
LoginPage
FormPage
Dashboard
```

LoginPage and FormPage are small components but Dashboard is a very big module.

My problems is i don't want to download the entire main bundle(1.5mb) on the login page (on page load which takes more time to download entire content) . i want to download the dashboard component related JS file chunk on dashboard component loading.

I am using ng-build --prod for production build

Is it possible to split the main bundle js based on component? Can I do the same split in vendor JS too?

Answer (score 0):

You can have lazyloaded modules using Angular router loadChildren. Based on user access URL, their corresponding module will be loaded on demand.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const app_routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: 'app/login/login.module#LoginModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    loadChildren: 'app/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
  },
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '/login' },
  { path: '**', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '/login' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(app_routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```